# Running multiple Fedlet applications configured against different IDPs on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam

I have a Tomcat server running a fedlet application which is configured against a single IDP. All the configuration files are located in their default location (i.e. ~/fedlet) and it works just fine.

What I would like to do is install another fedlet application which is configured against a different IDP on the same instance of Tomcat.

Within the fedlet app there is a `conf` directory, so is it possible to update the fedlet so that it gets its configurations from the local conf directory instead?

Looking at the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847.pdf) you can change the location of the config directory by setting the `com.sun.identity.fedlet.home` property. But that's a JVM level property so will apply to all fedlet applications running in my environment.

Just to be clear, I don't want to configure a single fedlet application to use multiple IDPs, I want to create a second completely separate fedlet application which is configured against a completely independent IDP from the first fedlet app.

Any pointers welcome.

Cheers,
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to link you provide it is not possible to run multiple instances of Fedlet on the same instance of Tomcat:

*You can deploy multiple instances of the Oracle OpenSSO Fedlet on the same host as
follows:
Multiple Java Fedlet instances can run on the same host server if each Fedlet
instance runs in its own Java Virtual Machine (JVM).*

So, you can not configure the same fedlet.war to be configured against an additional IDP.
You may install on the same host additional instance of Tomcat (that runs on different ports) and configure its fedlet.war against an additional IDP.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I must admit, I missed that bit of the documentation so thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Great! You can put Apache proxy and configure it to 2 Tomcat servers using the same host